How could G-d allow Judaism to be deprived of leadership?
I read a book called Letters: Hebrew-Catholic to Mr. Isaacs by David Goldstein, who was a convert to Catholicism.  One of his arguments is that Judaism has ceased to be a religion the way it was in ancient times.  For example, the chain of ordination was lost so that rabbis no longer essentially differ from normal Jews.  This is why many rabbis now have several "ordinations" which are really just letters of recommendation.  Another thing is the loss of the Sanhedrin.  This seems problematic because how do you know what the Sanhedrin actually said?  If the Sanhedrin still existed we could argue about whether or not it is actually infallible, but as it stands it amounts to nothing more than a story. In other words, if the Sanhedrin said they were making a decision that was binding for all time (Dt 17), don't you think that is implicitly saying that they will be around in the future to confirm it?  Goldstein concludes that the fact that it went out of existence shows that it was not actually infallible, and therefore Judaism is not true. Someone might argue that it doesn't matter because Judaism hasn't been splintered into hundreds of factions like Protestantism, but isn't that just arbitrarily defining everyone else, for example Christians, out?

Our rabbis are not priests - we are perfectly comfortable with them being no different to “normal Jews”. We have never claimed that the Sanhedrin is infallible. In general, trying to judge Judaism on the basis of catholic doctrines is not going to be particularly fruitful.

"In other words, if the Sanhedrin said they were making a decision that was binding for all time, don't you think that is implicitly saying that they will be around in the future to confirm it?" I can't follow the argument here. Their decision is binding because we respect their authority, because the Torah respects their authority. We don't need them to be "around". (Of course, we want them back, because then they could make more decisions and we need that.) But this doesn't make sense to me.

"One of his arguments is that Judaism has ceased to be a religion the way it was in ancient times." It is certainly very different. We have no Temple, we have no prophets, we have no Sanhedrin. We only recently got back the land of Israel. - But what is the point? We still try to keep the Torah as best we can, because God gave us that mission, and I hope he is happy that we are loyal to our mission even when it is hard.

Why should I care what a convert out of Judaism has to say about Judaism?

@JoelK The problem with the laicization of the rabbis/judges is that all of their teachings are equal, so there can’t be a guarantee that they aren’t all teaching heresy.  It’s questionable how much of a guarantee even that could give without an infallible central authority.  I know that the rabbinic literature claims that there was never an infallible authority in Judaism because they realized the loss of said authority was a big problem, but this is impossible.

@JoelK If God said that anyone who disobeys the Sanhedrin should be killed (Dt 17), doesn’t it follow that He would never let the Sanhedrin make a mistake?  If God is obligating people to listen to a revelation long after it is given, then He has to give them a reliable way of knowing what that revelation is.  A book doesn’t work because it has to be copied and it can be corrupted.

@JoelK Collegial authority doesn’t work because if there’s a disagreement, there’s no way to know who to listen to.  The only way this is possible is with a living, infallible individual (or body I suppose).  The infallibility of the Torah also proves this.  Noninfallible people cannot maintain an infallible book.  Thus God must have established a living, infallible authority, and He would never have let it disappear.

@MichoelR Because if it stopped existing, then, for example, different groups of people could claim that they said different things, and neither of them would have the authority to be believed.  Or everyone could just lie about what they said and there would be no way to know.  Or people could claim that it never actually existed and was just a story to justify some other people’s teachings.  You said their decision is binding because we respect their authority.

@MichoelR So notice the authority is actually coming from the people alive today (who all deny having such authority).  This is the sola scriptura paradox.  The Torah has to take its credibility from people alive now, because people can change things and make forgeries.  The Torah also doesn’t tell you what the Sanhedrin said.

@MichoelR This all goes to show that an infallible authority cannot cease to exist, and if it does, then it wasn’t infallible.  You try to keep the Torah, but you can’t because you’re not grounded by infallible leadership, and for all you know, two thousand years of self-appointed rabbis have taken Judaism off the deep end.

There are like ninety assumptions in your statements that don't agree with the way Torah Jews approach the topic.

I’ve read your question. I’ve read your comments. You’re not looking for an answer. Your statements are based on random assumptions and Christian-invented strawmen, and you’re not listening when we point out those specific assumptions and strawmen. You just want to preach. Take your lies and leave.

Also, what does the last sentence have to do with anything? I mean, nothing else in your post has any linear logical coherence, but the last sentence is random even within the context of your post. What the heck, man?

Is the Judaism area of Stack Exchange generally considered a suitable place for Christian missionaries to go hunting for prey?  This "question" really has nothing to do with Judaism; it's all about the OP's religious beliefs and bizarre approach to logic.

Goldstein, who I take it from your comments is a formerly Jewish convert to Catholicism, argues that Judaism is not and never was true, based on the fact that the Sanhedrin ceased to exist.
His argument, as you present it, appears to amount to: Judaism does not fit some standard I made up five minutes ago, therefore it is false.  This is not a good argument. Why should Judaism be "responsible" to live up to a standard made up quite recently, and probably with the specific intent of "disproving" it?  But let's look at it in more detail.
First, if he's right, then JC was wrong, for JC was a believing Jew who taught that one should obey the Rabbis.(Matthew 23:2-3)  Alternatively, Matthew incorrectly reports on the statements of JC, in which case the New Testament is false.
I would think that a believing Catholic would be uncomfortable disagreeing with JC and/or the Gospels, but what do I know?
Next, let us imagine an alternate history where the Romans did not succeed in stamping out rabbinic ordination, and the Sanhedrin as an institution still existed today.  Do you suppose that the same individuals that composed the Sanhedrin in ancient times would still be alive and able to personally confirm their teachings?  Obviously, they would all have died by now, and their students, and many generations of their students, and today's Sanhedrin would be composed of...the same rabbis that we respect and rely upon today.
So what would be different in terms of that?  We accept the records that have come down to us of the deliberations and rulings of the ancient Sanhedrin and the rabbis that composed it, just as we would do if the Sanhedrin as an institution still existed.
Another point; the Sanhedrin is not, and never claimed to be, infallible.  There is an entire Talmudic tractate, Horayos, which deals with what we do when the Sanhedrin realizes that it has made a very serious error.  The Sanhedrin was authoritative.  You might compare it to the Supreme Court, which might be wrong as a matter of logic and fact, but the rulings of which remain supreme until such time as the Court reverses itself.
As for defining Christians out...well, of course we do.  Idolators are not in; how could they be?  They are out in exactly the same way that worshipers of Ba'al or Zeus were out, back when they existed.

I don't agree with your comparison of idolators and early Christians. It seems fairly obvious to a lay reader of the Christian scriptures and scholars that early Christians were practicing Jews and often Pharisees. It seems like us being antagonistic toward them made them even more pagan. But overall great answer so take my +1

I am comparing modern Christians to idolators, or rather, stating that they are idolators.  They fit the definition, for they worship something (in their case, JC) which is not Hashem.  But thank you for your comments, @Aaron.

@Aaron what's your source for saying that Pharisees were among the early Christians? Other than Paul, the literally self-described grifter (I Corinthians 9:19-23).

@YehoshuaKahan  He wasn't saying the Sanhedrin was never infallible. He was arguing that it was transferred to the Papacy (most likely in John 20:22) and that this was then verified by the Sanhedrin going out of existence.

@YehoshuaKahan If they still had the charism of infallibility then you would know they were telling the truth about their predecessors.

@wmasse  Which is all a non-starter, as the Sanhedrin never had nor claimed infallibility.  Even Moses himself, the greatest human being to ever live, was capable of error when he spoke on his own initiative (as versus when the Voice of Prophecy spoke through him).  Hashem is infallible.  All human beings err.  And certainly all Popes were entirely in error, starting with their making the error of being Christians.

@YehoshuaKahan I know that Rabbinic Judaism claims the Sanhedrin never had infallibility because they realize this would undermine them, but this is logically incoherent (see my other comments).  The verses that tractate is based off of are talking about something like a kosher food recall.

@YehoshuaKahan Interpreting them as a denial of objective religious truth is a bit unwarranted, especially given the Sanhedrin could kill anyone who disagreed with them.  God is infallible, but only a few people have direct communication from Him. So if all human beings err, then all of your religious teachings could be wrong.

@Yehuda Acts15:5 discusses how the council in Jerusalem is made up at least partly of still practicing pharisees. And they have issues with Paul and his non Jewish contingent of followers

@YehoshuaKahan Infallibility does not mean they never sin, it just means they never teach error in their capacity as religious leader.  There have even been popes who were heretics, but they never taught their views as Catholic doctrine.

@wmasse, Catholic doctrine is severe error from top to bottom.  When you start with the belief that a human being--any human being--is the Deity, you are laying your foundations in the most severe error.  So your claims of Papal infallibility are not impressive to me, at all.

It's unfortunate that when religious people discuss why they don't believe religion x, they feel a need to try and state why religion x is not true overall. And one of the most common ways to go about this is to make a fake argument that the religion itself didn't claim, and then attack that fake argument.
So for example, David Goldstein makes this argument: "...Judaism has ceased to be a religion the way it was in ancient times. For example, the chain of ordination was lost so that rabbis no longer essentially differ from normal Jews."
His entire premise is flawed because Judaism in ancient times did not have leaders BY DESIGN. It was designed this way by God Himself. In the ancient Israelite religion only God was King. Priests could make judgments of law, but the law itself was given by God and could only be applied or interpreted, not new laws created by Priests. Prophets or Judges could rise up to also bring clarity to the law and encourage people to repent. We didn't even have a temple, just a tent in Shiloh that people would make pilgrimages to. So all in all, there were no kings, there were no leaders, everyone did what was right in their own eyes.
Judges 21:25

כה  בַּיָּמִים הָהֵם, אֵין מֶלֶךְ בְּיִשְׂרָאֵל:  אִישׁ הַיָּשָׁר בְּעֵינָיו, יַעֲשֶׂה.  {ש}  25 In those days there was no king in Israel; every man did that which was right in his own eyes.

This led to the children of Israel asking a prophet to ask God for an actual human leader on this earth like every other religion and kingdom has.
1 Samuel 8:1-22

שְׁמוּאֵל א א  וַיְהִי, כַּאֲשֶׁר זָקֵן שְׁמוּאֵל; וַיָּשֶׂם
אֶת-בָּנָיו שֹׁפְטִים, לְיִשְׂרָאֵל.  1 And it came to pass, when
Samuel was old, that he made his sons judges over Israel. ב  וַיְהִי
שֶׁם-בְּנוֹ הַבְּכוֹר יוֹאֵל, וְשֵׁם מִשְׁנֵהוּ אֲבִיָּה--שֹׁפְטִים,
בִּבְאֵר שָׁבַע.  2 Now the name of his first-born was Joel; and the
name of his second, Abijah; they were judges in Beer-sheba. ג
וְלֹא-הָלְכוּ בָנָיו בִּדְרָכָו, וַיִּטּוּ אַחֲרֵי הַבָּצַע;
וַיִּקְחוּ-שֹׁחַד--וַיַּטּוּ, מִשְׁפָּט.  {פ}     3 And his sons walked
not in his ways, but turned aside after lucre, and took bribes, and
perverted justice. {P} ד  וַיִּתְקַבְּצוּ, כֹּל זִקְנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל;
וַיָּבֹאוּ אֶל-שְׁמוּאֵל, הָרָמָתָה.  4 Then all the elders of Israel
gathered themselves together, and came to Samuel unto Ramah. ה
וַיֹּאמְרוּ אֵלָיו, הִנֵּה אַתָּה זָקַנְתָּ, וּבָנֶיךָ, לֹא הָלְכוּ
בִּדְרָכֶיךָ; עַתָּה, שִׂימָה-לָּנוּ מֶלֶךְ
לְשָׁפְטֵנוּ--כְּכָל-הַגּוֹיִם.   5 And they said unto him: 'Behold,
thou art old, and thy sons walk not in thy ways; now make us a king to
judge us like all the nations.' ו  וַיֵּרַע הַדָּבָר, בְּעֵינֵי
שְׁמוּאֵל, כַּאֲשֶׁר אָמְרוּ, תְּנָה-לָּנוּ מֶלֶךְ לְשָׁפְטֵנוּ;
וַיִּתְפַּלֵּל שְׁמוּאֵל, אֶל-יְהוָה.  {פ}    6 But the thing displeased
Samuel, when they said: 'Give us a king to judge us.' And Samuel
prayed unto the LORD. {P} ז  וַיֹּאמֶר יְהוָה, אֶל-שְׁמוּאֵל, שְׁמַע
בְּקוֹל הָעָם, לְכֹל אֲשֶׁר-יֹאמְרוּ אֵלֶיךָ:  כִּי לֹא אֹתְךָ
מָאָסוּ, כִּי-אֹתִי מָאֲסוּ מִמְּלֹךְ עֲלֵיהֶם.   7 And the LORD said
unto Samuel: 'Hearken unto the voice of the people in all that they
say unto thee; for they have not rejected thee, but they have rejected
Me, that I should not be king over them. ח  כְּכָל-הַמַּעֲשִׂים
אֲשֶׁר-עָשׂוּ, מִיּוֹם הַעֲלֹתִי אוֹתָם מִמִּצְרַיִם וְעַד-הַיּוֹם
הַזֶּה, וַיַּעַזְבֻנִי, וַיַּעַבְדוּ אֱלֹהִים אֲחֵרִים--כֵּן הֵמָּה
עֹשִׂים, גַּם-לָךְ.   8 According to all the works which they have done
since the day that I brought them up out of Egypt even unto this day,
in that they have forsaken Me, and served other gods, so do they also
unto thee. ט  וְעַתָּה, שְׁמַע בְּקוֹלָם:  אַךְ, כִּי-הָעֵד תָּעִיד
בָּהֶם, וְהִגַּדְתָּ לָהֶם, מִשְׁפַּט הַמֶּלֶךְ אֲשֶׁר יִמְלֹךְ
עֲלֵיהֶם.  {ס}    9 Now therefore hearken unto their voice; howbeit thou
shalt earnestly forewarn them, and shalt declare unto them the manner
of the king that shall reign over them.' {S} י  וַיֹּאמֶר שְׁמוּאֵל,
אֵת כָּל-דִּבְרֵי יְהוָה, אֶל-הָעָם, הַשֹּׁאֲלִים מֵאִתּוֹ מֶלֶךְ.
{ס}   10 And Samuel told all the words of the LORD unto the people that
asked of him a king. {S} יא  וַיֹּאמֶר--זֶה יִהְיֶה מִשְׁפַּט
הַמֶּלֶךְ, אֲשֶׁר יִמְלֹךְ עֲלֵיכֶם:  אֶת-בְּנֵיכֶם יִקָּח, וְשָׂם לוֹ
בְּמֶרְכַּבְתּוֹ וּבְפָרָשָׁיו, וְרָצוּ, לִפְנֵי מֶרְכַּבְתּוֹ.   11
And he said: 'This will be the manner of the king that shall reign
over you: he will take your sons, and appoint them unto him, for his
chariots, and to be his horsemen; and they shall run before his
chariots. יב  וְלָשׂוּם לוֹ, שָׂרֵי אֲלָפִים וְשָׂרֵי חֲמִשִּׁים;
וְלַחֲרֹשׁ חֲרִישׁוֹ וְלִקְצֹר קְצִירוֹ, וְלַעֲשׂוֹת
כְּלֵי-מִלְחַמְתּוֹ וּכְלֵי רִכְבּוֹ.     12 And he will appoint them
unto him for captains of thousands, and captains of fifties; and to
plow his ground, and to reap his harvest, and to make his instruments
of war, and the instruments of his chariots. יג  וְאֶת-בְּנוֹתֵיכֶם,
יִקָּח, לְרַקָּחוֹת וּלְטַבָּחוֹת, וּלְאֹפוֹת.    13 And he will take
your daughters to be perfumers, and to be cooks, and to be bakers. יד
וְאֶת-שְׂדוֹתֵיכֶם וְאֶת-כַּרְמֵיכֶם וְזֵיתֵיכֶם, הַטּוֹבִים--יִקָּח;
וְנָתַן, לַעֲבָדָיו.  14 And he will take your fields, and your
vineyards, and your oliveyards, even the best of them, and give them
to his servants. טו  וְזַרְעֵיכֶם וְכַרְמֵיכֶם, יַעְשֹׂר; וְנָתַן
לְסָרִיסָיו, וְלַעֲבָדָיו.    15 And he will take the tenth of your
seed, and of your vineyards, and give to his officers, and to his
servants. טז  וְאֶת-עַבְדֵיכֶם וְאֶת-שִׁפְחוֹתֵיכֶם וְאֶת-בַּחוּרֵיכֶם
הַטּוֹבִים, וְאֶת-חֲמוֹרֵיכֶם--יִקָּח; וְעָשָׂה, לִמְלַאכְתּוֹ.   16
And he will take your men-servants, and your maid-servants, and your
goodliest young men, and your asses, and put them to his work. יז
צֹאנְכֶם, יַעְשֹׂר; וְאַתֶּם, תִּהְיוּ-לוֹ לַעֲבָדִים.    17 He will
take the tenth of your flocks; and ye shall be his servants. יח
וּזְעַקְתֶּם, בַּיּוֹם הַהוּא, מִלִּפְנֵי מַלְכְּכֶם, אֲשֶׁר
בְּחַרְתֶּם לָכֶם; וְלֹא-יַעֲנֶה יְהוָה אֶתְכֶם, בַּיּוֹם הַהוּא.     18
And ye shall cry out in that day because of your king whom ye shall
have chosen you; and the LORD will not answer you in that day.' יט
וַיְמָאֲנוּ הָעָם, לִשְׁמֹעַ בְּקוֹל שְׁמוּאֵל; וַיֹּאמְרוּ לֹּא, כִּי
אִם-מֶלֶךְ יִהְיֶה עָלֵינוּ.  19 But the people refused to hearken
unto the voice of Samuel; and they said: 'Nay; but there shall be a
king over us; כ  וְהָיִינוּ גַם-אֲנַחְנוּ, כְּכָל-הַגּוֹיִם;
וּשְׁפָטָנוּ מַלְכֵּנוּ וְיָצָא לְפָנֵינוּ, וְנִלְחַם
אֶת-מִלְחֲמֹתֵנוּ.    20 that we also may be like all the nations; and
that our king may judge us, and go out before us, and fight our
battles.' כא  וַיִּשְׁמַע שְׁמוּאֵל, אֵת כָּל-דִּבְרֵי הָעָם;
וַיְדַבְּרֵם, בְּאָזְנֵי יְהוָה.  {פ}     21 And Samuel heard all the
words of the people, and he spoke them in the ears of the LORD. {P} כב
וַיֹּאמֶר יְהוָה אֶל-שְׁמוּאֵל שְׁמַע בְּקוֹלָם, וְהִמְלַכְתָּ לָהֶם
מֶלֶךְ; וַיֹּאמֶר שְׁמוּאֵל אֶל-אַנְשֵׁי יִשְׂרָאֵל, לְכוּ אִישׁ
לְעִירוֹ.  {פ}    22 And the LORD said to Samuel: 'Hearken unto their
voice, and make them a king.'

Pharisaical Judaism claims to go back to Sinai through Moses. And I'm not going to say that argument is false, but I find little evidence of it in the Bible, and even less so in archaeology and extrabiblical historical accounts.
But we do find lots of evidence for the beginnings of Pharisaical Judaism starting after the Babylonian exile with Ezra/Nehemiah and it becomes uncontentested historical reality by the time we reach the Mishnah. We are no longer dealing with ancient leaderless Judaism, we are saturated with potential leaders from the priestly line, the sanhedrin, the Rabbis, and princes who are descended from David.
And so I reject David Goldstein's arguments outright. If anything, Judaism returned to being more ancient by the loss of semicha and the loss of kings and temple. Because God originally orchestrated Judaism to have only One Leader, God Himself.

I am surprised that you claim to find little evidence in Scripture for "Pharisaical Judaism."  Virtually every commandment in the Torah is, given only Scriptural text, obscure and opaque.  "Guard the Sabbath day to make it holy."  Of what does this guarding consist?  Scripture does not say.  "Tie them on your arms."  What are we to tie on our arms, and how?  Scripture does not say.  "Thou shalt not murder."  Is abortion murder?  Scripture does not say.
I also question your characterization of ancient Judaism as leaderless.  Surely Moses was the leader of the nation  (next comment)

(continuation from previous) in his time, and he appointed the Elders to assist him.  After him, Joshua was the leader of the nation.
While there were indeed interstitial periods between the reign of one Judge and the next when there was no overall leader, it seems odd to ignore the period of Moses and of Joshua, and the reigns of the Judges themselves, and declare the "leaderless" periods the norm.  And of course, even then there were courts and judges, as the Torah specifically commands.
@Aaron

@YehoshuaKahan Moses taught Israelitism to the Israelites. He was a lawgiver, he was a religious leader. But he was no king, and his children held no status either. They were not trained in the law or considered to be anything other than normal Israelites. The same is true of Joshua. They had missions, missions needed leaders. But in terms of the religion, Moses setup elders to help render judgments in cases where the law is obscure. This was first done with the 70 elders, and scripture says the elders of the land and the priests can also fulfill this role.

@YehoshuaKahan Making the argument that some of Judaism's laws are obscure and require clarity is a good argument. Saying that de facto means it was Pharisee Judaism is not a good argument. The Sadduccees/Priests also claim their right as priests was to render clarity in the law and they learned how to do this going back to Sinai. But at least for them scripture states that they will have this position and power, whereas Rabbi, Sanhedrin, and anything remotely close to Pharisee Judaism is missing from the text. So I find priestly claims to ancient Judaism to be stronger.

@YehoshuaKahan I consider myself a Rabbinate Jew, and I believe Rabbinate Judaism's interpretation of the Bible and God is the most correct. That doesn't mean I'll give them a pass about inserting themselves into antiquity when we have little evidence for it. I have lots of Christians in the periphery of my life who also insert all sorts of things into the ancient text to justify their current religious practice. That's all fine and dandy, but it doesn't make it true just because it sounds nice and helps your religious practice "make more sense" now.

I see that this is likely to be a lengthy discussion.  Perhaps we should take it to a private channel.  What do you think?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
